# multiple sub query, count more sons but whit a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi! this work fine, but i need count more sons but whit a condition

```
select t1.*,(select count(*)
 from tabl t2 
 where t2.tabl = t1.id) as  sons
 from tabl t1 where tabl.sons = ?;
```

I try this, but receive the following error...

> SQL ERROR: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
 select t1.*,(select count(*),(select count(*) from tbl1 t3 where t3.type = 3) as Johnny
 from tabl t2 
 where t2.tabl = t1.id) as  sons
 from tabl t1 where tabl.sons = ?;
```

please, and thanks

Edit:
this do exactly i want, but i think is not the correct way to do
(i changed the names sorry, but it look better)

```
select m1.*,
(select count(*) from node m2 where m2.nodeid = m1.id) as child,
(select count(*) from node m3 where m3.type = 3 and m3.nodeid = m1.id) as del,
(select count(*) from node m3 where m3.type = 1 and m3.nodeid = m1.id) as edit,
(select count(*) from node m3 where m3.type = 4 and m3.nodeid = m1.id) as protect,
(select count(*) from node m3 where m3.type = 2 and m3.nodeid = m1.id) as move  
from node m1 where nodeid = ?
```

```
+----+--------+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+
| id | nodeid | type | child | del  | edit | protect | move |
+----+--------+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+
| 1  |   null |    0 |     3 |    0 |    1 |       1 |    1 |
+----+--------+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+

+----+--------+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+
| id | nodeid | type | child | del  | edit | protect | move |
+----+--------+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+
| 34 |      1 |    1 |     7 |    2 |    1 |       1 |    1 |
| 23 |      1 |    2 |     3 |    1 |    0 |       0 |    0 |
| 32 |      1 |    3 |     2 |    0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |
+----+--------+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+
```

basically how many children are and how many are of each type xd

Comment: Please show some sample data and your desired results from it.

Comment: Also, your table structure would be useful. Is `tabl` different to `tbl1`?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 has got the window functions. Therefore, you can write your query in it like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id) AS sons,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.type = 3 THEN t1.type END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id) AS Johnny
FROM tabl t1
WHERE t1.sons = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define multiple columns to one column.

```
(select count(*),(select count(*) from tbl1 t3 where t3.type = 3) as Johnny
 from tabl t2  where t2.tabl = t1.id) as  sons
```

sons : one column, count(*),,,Johnny : multiple column

Please change it to the following sql...

```
(select count(*) from tabl t2 where t2.tabl=t1.id), (select count(*) from tbl1 t3 where t3.type=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by id) as sons,
       sum(type = 3) over (partition by id) as johnny
from tabl t
having sons = ?;
```

MySQL extends the `having` clause so it can filter on table aliases in a non-aggregation query.